# Did anyone work with set_center method in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm using AnyLogic for a project in Supply Chain. I would love to ask those who have seen the predefined model in AnyLogic.

Its path is in: Welcome > Example Models > Supply Chains and Logistics > Product delivery. In the model they used a function called `set_center` (You can find it in the Main).
You can find below the code in AnyLogic

```
for (Distributor distributor : distributors) 
    distributor.set_center(
        distributor.getNearestAgentByRoute(manufacturingCenters));
```

For my project, I created a model inspired from the predefined model described above but the function `set_center` didn't work. It tells me in the console

```
The method set_center(shiptopoint.getNearestAgentByRoute(retailers)) is undefined for the type Shiptopoint
```

Where `shiptopoint` and `retailers` are agents that I created for my model (They are both population agents)

I tried to find the Java Code but I didn't find it.
Does anyone have a clue please?

Answer (score 2):

`set_center(...)` is an automatically created method for the parameter `center` in the agent type `Distributor`. Each parameter you create gets such a method, see [AnyLogic help on parameters](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/data/Parameters.html?resultof=%22%70%61%72%61%6D%65%74%65%72%22%20%22%70%61%72%61%6D%65%74%22%20).

You lack a parameter `center` in your agent type, so there is no such method.

Comment: Hi @Chloe, Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)